# Concurrent Access within a Big InMemory B+Index

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, b-tree, concurrentmodification

I am currently designing around a big memory index structure (several giga bytes). The index is actually a RTree which leafes are BTrees (dont ask). It supports a special query and pushes it to the logical limit.

Since those nodes are soley search nodes I ask my self how to best make it parallel.

I know of six solutions so far:

1. Block reads when a write is scheduled. The tree is completely blocked until the last read is finished and then the write is performed and after the write the tree can yet again used for multiple reads. (reads need no locking).
2. Clone Nodes to change and reuse existing nodes (including leafs) and switch between both by simply yet again stop reads switch and done. Since leaf pointers must be altered also the leaf pointers might become their own collection making it possible to switch modifications atomar and changes can be redo to a second version to avoid copy of the pointer on each insert.
3. Use independent copies of the index like double buffering. Update one copy of the index, switch it. Once noone reads the old index, alter this index in the same way. This way the change can be done without blocking existing reads. If another insert hits the tree in a reasonable amount of time these changes can also be done.
4. Use a serial share nothing architecture so each search thread has its own copy. Since a thread can only alter its tree after a single read is performed, this would be also lock free and simple. Due reads are spread evenly for each worker thread (being bound to a certain core), the throughput would not be harmed.
5. Use write / read locks for each node being about to be written and do only block a subtree during write. This would involve additional operations against the tree since splitting and merging would propagate upwards and therefore require a repass of the insert (since expanding locks upwards (parentwise) would introduce the chance of a deadlock). Since Split and Merge are not that frequent if you have a higher page size, this would also be a good way. Actually currently my BTree implementation currently uses a similar mechanism by spliting a node and reinsert the value unless no split is needed (which is not optimal but more simple).
6. Use double buffer for each node like the shadow cache for databases where each page is switched between two versions. So everytime a node is modified a copy is modified and once a read is issued the old versions are used or the new one. Each node gets a version number and the version that is more close to the active version (latest change) is choosen. To switch between to version, one needs only an atomar change on the root information. This way the tree can be altered and used. This swith can be done every time but it must be ensured that no read is using the old version when overriding the new one. This method has the possibility to not interfer with cache locality in order to link leafs and alike. But it also requires twice the amount of memory since a back buffer must be present but saves allocation time and might be good for a high frequency of changes.

With all that thoughts what is best? I know it depends but what is done in the wild? If there are 10 read threads (or even more) and being blocked by a single write operation I guess this is nothing I really want.

Also how about L3, L2 and L1 cache and in scenarios with multiple CPUs? Any issues on that? The beauty of the double buffering is the chance that those reads hitting the old version are still working with the correct cache version.

The version of creating a fresh copy of a node is quite not appealing. So what is meet in the wild of todays database landscapes?

[update]

By rereading the post, I wonder if using the write locks for split and merge would be better suited by creating replacement nodes since for a split and a merge I need to copy somewhat the half of elements around, those operations are very rare and so actually copy a node completely would do the trick by replacing this node in the parent node which is a simple and fast operation. This way the actual blocks for reads would be very limited and since we create copies anyway, the blocking only happens when the new nodes are replaced. Since during those access leafs may not be altered it is unimportant since the information density has not changed. But again this needs for every access of a node a increment and decrement of a read lock and checking for intended write locks. This all is overhead and this all is blocking further reads.

[Update2]

Solution 7. (currently favored)

Currently we favor a double buffer for the internal (non-leaf) nodes and use something similar to row locking.

Our logical tables that we try to decompose using those index structure (which is all a index does) results in using algebra of sets on those information. I noticed that this algebra of sets is linear (O(m+n) for intersection and union) and gives us the chance to lock each entry being part of such operation.

By double buffering the internal nodes (which is not hard to implement nor does it cost much (about <1% memory overhead)) we can live problem free on that issue not blocking too much read operations.

Since we batch modifications in a certain way it is very rarely seen that a given column is updated but once it is, it takes more time since those modifications might go in the thousands for this single entry.

So the goal is to alter the algebra of sets used to simply intersect those columns being currently modified later on. Since only one column is modified at a time such operation would only block once. And for everyone currently reading it, the write operation has to wait. And guess what, once a write operation waits, it usually lets another write operation of another column taking place that is not bussy. We calculate the propability of such a block to be very very low. So we dont need to care.

The locking mechanism is done using check for write, check for write intention, add read, check for write again and procced with the read. So there is no explicit object locking. We access fixed areas of bytes and if the structure is clear everything critical is planed to move into a c++ version to make it somewhat faster (2x we guess and this only takes one person one or two weeks to do especially if you use a Java to C++ translator).

The only effect that is now also important might be the caching issue since it invalidates L1 caches and maybe L2 too. So we plan to collect all modifications on such a table / index to be scheduled to run within 1 or more minutes timeshare but be evenly distributed to not make a system that has performance hickhups.

If you know of anything that helps us please go ahead.

Comment: What about to put everything into database and access it trough it? Thounsands of workhours were spent to make this as fast as possible...

Comment: Negative this is a special memory structure to drive a special single purpose query. Also a database comes again with index, statistics, query optimizer all the fun stuff you hire 10 people to get a mid size oracle database functional and operating. Also you start to use Query languages and all that stuff. Kills you off in the long run. And how long does such an implementation take? A week? Maybe less. As I wrote: "Dont ask".

Comment: And by no means a general purpose database is never as fast as possible. We talk here by magnitudes of speed. Ever thought a database that is using an R-Index of BTrees which adapt by being split or merged? And we use those index to create unions of selected entries within the BTree so we actually use a BTree for a certain region and use only a bunch of entries.

Comment: To give you an impression: For a query result we touch up to 100k information shattered across the BTree found. And we have a single thread throughput of about 10k answers since those operations are closely located within a leaf also using a custom storage scheme you barely can find in composite index structures of a database. There is no way a ordinary database can provide this. I guess you could be lucky to see 100 or so. Also we use datacompression on the go so we also waste half to a quarter of space a normal database would. And once you start using custom datastructures you never go back.

Comment: I like option 3 myself. Only down sides would seem to be a doubling of memory requirements, and, your updates must be serialized.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no bigger application/system which does not use database. For simple reason - if there is a bunch of well educated and talented people spending thousand of hours to develop system, which is as fast as possible, you simply can not be better :).

PS : 100k rows in a standard b-tree is found in depth 3, as standard b-tree has 50-100 chillds...

PS2 : Having an exuses does not solve the problem

PS3 : There is a little probablitiy that you REALLY do no need use database, but it is unlikely one.

Comment: @libik Think about stack overflow. They implemented their own tag engine. Think about google, ebay, amazon and whom ever. Everyone implemented their own search engine. cnet used Solr but uses as I understood way more memory and CPU power as needed. Sure Hardware is cheap but developing a special custom database is cheaper. Especially if you strip everything down. I am from the consultant business of performance engineering. I know Oracle by heart and well I dont want to use it.

Comment: And with the solution we build a 256GB node (which is running only one Java application) you have effectively 1TB memory due the string and value compression using language specific dictionaries so you dont have the weak performance of deflate for short strings and also have no dynamic lookup tables. We can compress/decompress about 500Million characters per second per core. So in the end having your own special database is fun and has many advantages and the best is to avoid a query optimizer but use always the best way to query? Oracle has roughly 10 ways to handle data. Thats nothing.

Comment: PS: About the 100k Rows out of 100Million and we have about 2000 childs per node but those are organized in tree like fashion itself to avoid heavy copying. And once you found your first entry its faster to go through the leafs for a given distance than to search it again. And yes those tree access of 100k is dead slow. I have another performance problem when it comes to event log analysation and some string decoposition for 10GB only it was more than 20times faster to use a HashIndex rather than a BTree of 256nodesize. So it really matters what you do and how.

Comment: @James Option 3 is quite a good idea. Searializing the modifications is usually a very good solution. But I have problems with throwing half the memory out of the window. I currently experiment with duplicated internal nodes and non duplicated leaf nodes and lock them. This way the most costly operations of spliting merging and everything can be done simple and without locking and the modification of a leaf is fast and straight forward but complicates the read process. But for this special table we usually have batches of modifications.

Comment: I update the post for the current final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noone replied I would like to summarize what we (I) finally did. The structure is now separated. We have a RTree which leaf are actually Tables. Those tables can be even remote so we have a distribution way that is mostly transparent thanks to RMI and proxies.

The rest was simply easy. The RTree has the way to advise a table to split and this split is again a table. This split is been done on a single maschine and transfered to another if it has to be remote. Merge is almost similar.

This remote also is true for threads bound to different CPUs to avoid cache issues.

About the modification in memory it is as I already suggested. we duplicate internal nodes and turned the table 90° and adapted the algebraic set algorithms to handle locked columns efficiently. The test for a single table is simple and compared to the 1000ends of entries per column not a performance issue after all. Deadlocks are also impossible since one column is used at a time so there is only one lock per thread. We experiment with doing columns in parallel which would increase the response time. We also think about binding columns to a given virtual core so there is no locking again since the column is in isolation and yet again the modification can be serialized.

This way one can utilize 20 cores and more per CPU and also avoid cache misses.